# Who is the person behind Roka ??

Tags: d-frag

[image]

In the following screenshot was taken in Episode 3 (16:26) of D-Fragment series. In that time, Roka Shibasaki seem role-playing herself as some sort of director in Japan. I would like to know who is the person she trying to portray ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am terrible at physiognomy but it looks like [Akira Kurosawa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_Kurosawa).

[image]

Comment: This is the image they're trying to copy: http://eng3122.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/akira_kurosawa_copy.jpg